# How to Get tax Percent of order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, taxes

Recently I have a task I need to add a column in sales order grid and that column will show tax percent of order.Tax are applying according to the postcode of address,I tried below code

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(100001045,'increment_id');nt();
echo "<pre>"; print_r( $order->getFullTaxInfo());
```

But `getFullTaxInfo()` method sometimes not giving anything.

Can anybody let me know how I will get the tax percent of the order by order id?

Comment: I don't think you can get tax percent of an order as tax classes are applied per product and each order can have more than one products.

Comment: when we open any order we can see in order total section Tax Total I need the percent of that. From getFullTaxInfo() method I got the percent but this method only gives tax info for process status order if order status is complete its not showing percent of tax.What should be the reason